# issue with responsive cell

Tags: html, css

Dears,
am trying to build a simple page that have three blocks (cells), I am not able to make it responsive even the code is correct.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            html, body {
              height: 100%;
            }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<table style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
        <!-- Page body -->
        <div ID="PageBody">
            <table border="1" style="width: 98%; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" nowrap style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 450px;">
                  <div style="width: 100%; max-width: 450px; background-color: blue;">Main content</div>
                </td>
                <td align="center" nowrap><div>content 2</div></td>
                <td align="center" nowrap><div>content 3</div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        <!-- Page body -->
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need the first cell (Blue) never exceed 450px. plz advice

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is any reason for using table? I think is much easier to use divs instead of tables. try this code: https://codepen.io/Bobby-iv/pen/eYbLNGe

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">Main content
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">Content 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">content 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```